# Can I make separate controller for AJAX actions? (Magento 1.x)

Tags: magento-1.7, controllers, ajax, admin-controller

I have my custom module and everything works fine, but I would like to create separately controller for AJAX actions (AjaxController). Currently I Have only IndexController. Everytime I get:

**{"error":true,"message":"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."}**

Code snippets are below:

**Build URL:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    RECALC_SP_URL = "<?=$this->htmlEscape(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/productcreator_ajax/getSpecialPrice/'));?>";
</script>
```

**Part of config.xml*:*

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <productcreator after="Mage_Adminhtml">Aiti_ProductCreator_Adminhtml</productcreator>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**AJAX call:**

```
jQuery( "#margin_percent" ).change(function() {
    var $_this = jQuery( this );
    var store_id = 0;
    new Ajax.Request(RECALC_SP_URL, {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: {
            storeId: store_id,
            margin: $_this.val(),
            productId: jQuery('#productcreator_product_id').val(),
        },
        onSuccess: function (transport) {
            var response = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);

            jQuery("#special_price").val(response['special_price']);
        },
        onFailure: function () {

        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for some help!

Answer (score 0):

Below i have add new ajax request url in code. please review it

```
jQuery( "#margin_percent" ).change(function() {     
    var $_this = jQuery( this );
    var store_id = 0;
    /* margin is controller name. file name is like "marginController.php" & getPercent is function */
    new Ajax.Request('ajaxdata/margin/getPercent/', {
        method: 'get',
        parameters: {
            storeId: store_id,
            margin: $_this.val(),
            productId: jQuery('#productcreator_product_id').val(),
        },
        onSuccess: function (transport) {
            var response = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);

            jQuery("#special_price").val(response['special_price']);
        },
        onFailure: function () {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: My URL is ok, I'm sure - If ajax is sending by get method, all is ok....problem is only with post method.

Comment: using GET method. I have edit code please review it.

Comment: Is is not possible to use post method?

Comment: Yes . you to just edit method. Like method: 'post', or method: 'get',

Comment: If I edit method to post,  I have problem with form key - {"error":true,"message":"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."}

Comment: 1. Try to clear the cache from var/cache directory.
2. Then clear browser cache. Especially clear or delete cookies.
3. Remove app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php is exist.
Hope this helps you!